# Is it possible to assign a variable in a gulp task before running dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm trying to conditionally pipe a file stream based on the value of a variable, as a way to define two separate build environments (ie. development and production).

Some tasks can be run individually with a command-line flag like so:
`gulp scripts --env production`

And will then do some production-only pipeline steps:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  var jsFilter = filter(['*.js']),
  appFiles;

  return gulp.src(appFiles)
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe(concat('application-build.js'))
    .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', uglify()))
    .pipe(size())
    .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', gulp.dest('dist/js'), gulp.dest('tmp/js')))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }));
});
```

I have a `build` task that calls a number of other tasks as dependencies (including this `scripts` task for instance). I want this `build` task to assign a variable (`env`, in this case) *before* running task dependencies. Which means that this:

```
gulp.task('build', ['scripts', 'styles', 'otherstuff'], function() {
  env = 'production';
}
```

doesn't work, because the dependencies are run before the body of the task.

I currently have it implemented with `gulp.start`:

```
gulp.task('build', function() {
  env = 'production';
  gulp.start('scripts');
});
```

[But the `.start` method isn't actually part of gulp's public API](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/755#issuecomment-61884019) - it [comes from Orchestrator](https://github.com/orchestrator/orchestrator/blob/f3fcb93e3560afd0bc0c4acd5c5db7bd109414e7/index.js#L73) - and isn't intended to be used for anything. Plus, the equivalent method `gulp.run` was deprecated from the API awhile ago.

So I'm wondering - is there another way I could assign a variable in a task before running its dependencies?

(Or maybe there's a better way to to implement something like build environments in gulp?)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## THE RIGHT WAY

I disagree with @Justin. Defining an environmental variable with a task is a hackjob of an idea. This is better done with `gutil.env` this way.

```
gulp --env prod task

gulp.task( 'myTask', () => { console.log( gutil.env.env ) } )
```

Now from this point, you have `gulp.env.env` set.

Or, alternatively you can do like [this example in this ticket..](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/193) which addresses this from the developers of Gulp which first suggest to use an environmental variable, but provide this idiom..

```
function js(shouldMinify) {
    return gulp.src('./js/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulpif(shouldMinify, uglify()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
});

gulp.task('develop', function () {
    shouldMinify = false;
    return js(shouldMinify);
});

gulp.task('build', function () {
    shouldMinify = true;
    return js(shouldMinify);
});
```

That [same developer (phated)](https://github.com/phated) always says to use env...

> Not to mention, you should control this type of logic with environment variables or command line flags. - phated

Presumably, he's referring to the use of `gutil.noop()` in `gulp-util`'s docs:

```
// gulp should be called like this :
// $ gulp --type production
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('script.js'))
    // LOOK BELOW: if we don't send to uglify, we push to noop stream.
    .pipe(gutil.env.type === 'production' ? uglify() : gutil.noop())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

Comment: @JustinHoward good catch, removed. I copy-pasted that from the ticket on git.

Answer (score 13):

You could create a task specifically to set the environment and run it before your other tasks.

```
gulp.task('set-production', function() {
  env = 'production';
});

// Doesn't quite work because tasks are run in parallel
gulp.task('build', ['set-production', 'scripts', 'styles', 'otherstuff']);
```

The problem here is that your tasks will be run in parallel, meaning the `set-production` task may be run after the other tasks. You can solve this problem with the `run-sequence` package.

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
  runSequence('set-production', ['scripts', 'styles', 'otherstuff'], callback);
});
```

This will run the `set-production` task first, then run the `scripts`, `styles`, and `otherstuff` tasks in parallel.

Comment: Thanks! I'm liking this approach a lot better. Quick question - (I know this was used in `run-sequence`'s documentation but) why is there a callback at the end?

Comment: Since gulp tasks are asynchronous, the callback lets gulp know the task is done. That is needed if the task is declared as a dependency of another task.

Comment: Do we need the `set-production` task, couldn't we just set `env` variable directly before we run the sequence ?